# How works drag and drop quizz?

Tags: openedx

The GUI gives very hard to get sample code. Especially :

```
correct_answer = {
        '1':      [[100, 150], 100],
        '2':      [[300, 150], 100],
        '3':      [[500, 150], 100],
        '4':      [[700, 150], 100]}
```

**How to understand and use it ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's documented [there](http://doroob-course-staff-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/exercises_tools/drag_and_drop.html#create-a-drag-and-drop-problem).
The hard part it the  `'id': [[x coordinate, y coordinate], radius]`.

```
<problem>
Recreate the sentence : `Demain, je vais marche`.
   <customresponse>
        <drag_and_drop_input img="https://studio.edx.org/c4x/edX/DemoX/asset/L9_buckets.png">
            <draggable id="1" label="I"/>
            <draggable id="3" label="walk"/>
            <draggable id="4" label="tomorrow"/>
            <draggable id="2" label="will"/>
        </drag_and_drop_input>
        <answer type="loncapa/python">
correct_answer = {
        '1':      [[100, 150], 100],
        '2':      [[300, 150], 100],
        '3':      [[500, 150], 100],
        '4':      [[700, 150], 100]}
if draganddrop.grade(submission[0], correct_answer):
    correct = ['correct']
else:
    correct = ['incorrect']
        </answer>
    </customresponse>
</problem>
```